# Flutter How to custom button to achieve that shape?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to achieve three radio buttons or outlined buttons for buying plans from my app

that's what I want to make

[image]

and that's the code that I tried before but It didn't work very well as you can see at the next screenshot anyone can help me, please?

```
                SizedBox(
                  width: 250.0,
                  height: 60.0,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      const Positioned(
                        top: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        child: Text(
                          "%",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      OutlinedButton(
                          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                            side: const BorderSide(
                              color: mainColor,
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                const Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "1 year",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "EGP 150.00",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    const Text(
                                      "Save 60%",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.amberAccent,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "EGP 12.33 / month",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey[350],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

but that's what I got I don't know how to complete my code or how that top right corner position is made with its image.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `ClipPath` to achieve that effect on the `%` in the corner.

Here is the code for the delegate:

```dart
class CustomClipperCornerTab extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final double radius;

  CustomClipperCornerTab({super.reclip, required this.radius});

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(0, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, radius)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(size.width - radius, 0),
        radius: Radius.circular(radius),
        clockwise: false,
      )
      ..lineTo(0, 0)
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return oldClipper is! CustomClipperCornerTab || oldClipper.radius != radius;
  }
}
```

You can then use it in the widget tree like so:

```dart
ClipPath(
  clipper: CustomClipperCornerTab(radius: radius),
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.amberAccent,
    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 1.5),
    child: Text(
      "%",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: mainColor,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

I would also recommend moving the `Stack` into the `OutlinedButton.child` so that corner widget along with any other layers you add don't block gestures and will be covered by the inkwell effect on long press.

[Full dartpad example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=9de75f80a0e75d007b153999b656a6ea).

[ClipPath docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [ribbon_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/ribbon_widget) package

```
Ribbon(
  nearLength: 1.0,
  farLength: 1.0,
  title: '%',
  titleStyle: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  color: Colors.amberAccent,
  location: RibbonLocation.topEnd,
  child: OutlinedButton(...),
)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer I really didn't know there is package like that, but I choose the 1st answer as package maybe in the future stop working